# MariaDB - too many connections error on Laravel jobs table

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb, laravel-10

I have a web application that is built using Laravel with MariaDB database. We use "database" as the queue_driver for jobs.

A couple of times during the last ten days, we have been facing MariaDB "Too many connections" error. This brings down the application and can only be fixed after a MariaDB restart.

Every time this happened, the "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" query run on the database, revealed errors with inserting records into the jobs table. A sample row from "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" is below

```
| **** | **** | 127.0.0.1:****  | **** | Execute     |    238 | Update                                                        | insert into `jobs` (`queue`, `attempts`, `reserved_at`, `available_at`, `created_at`, `payload`) values ('default', 0, NULL, '****', '****', '****') |    0.000 |
```

Except for the state, which is "UPDATE", there does not seem to be anything common in the different results from the "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" output. The jobs mentioned in the "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" belong to different queues and different parts of the application.

Our server administrators mentioned that the following could be the problem:

> The queries are waiting for a commit but are never recieving this from the application/queue worker side. It is possible the queue worker or application gets an error or is reaching a limit and therefore never gives the commit to perform the query.

But I am not really sure what is the best way to debug this.

We are using:

Laravel Framework 10.34.2
PHP 8.2.11
MariaDB 10.6.16

Because the server administrator mentioned that it had to do something with queries not being committed, we tried to reproduce the same using different parts of the application that has jobs being dispatched from inside a DB transaction. But if I start a DB transaction and then do not commit it, I do not see the jobs queries in the "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" query result.
So not sure if DB transactions dispatching jobs is the culprit here.

**Edit**

We received further communication from the server administrators which is mentioned below:

1: A large amount of queries are inserted into the jobs table by an automated process from the application / worker.
2: These cause the amount of active threads to shoot up, in some cases actually hitting the limit of connected threads in MySQL
3: These queries wait to be committed, the database is waiting for a commit to finalize the queries.
RECORD LOCKS space id 484 page no 5356 n bits 16 index PRIMARY of table `salesdock`.`jobs` trx id 2642853988 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
4: The commit statement never appears to arrive, causing the queries remain 'active' until the 300 second wait timer has arrived.
5: After the 300 second 'lock_wait' timer has expired these queries are aborted.

The jobs table itself is rather small, the inserts appear to be simple consisting of some identifying fields and json formatted data.

Comment: Keep an eye on the process list and enable your mariadb's slow query log, and look for long running queries, or the same query multiple times. The one you show look like it could be 238 seconds, which is almost 4 minutes. If that's what you expect, that's fine, unless you have multiples of that same query running at the same time, which can hog connections. See which queries you can optimize, either by adding indexes, or taking the processing out of the database and into php.

Comment: Additionally [SHOW EXPLAIN FOR {connection number}](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-explain/) can show how its executing. Your job queue uses [SKIP LOCKED](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/#skip-locked) right? Including table structure (from SHOW CREATE TABLE) and UPDATE query could at least validate index efficiency.

Comment: Are you running your own server?  Or is this in a cloud?  _Decrease_ the number of connections the _web server_ supports.

Comment: If in the process you have included lock for updates, be warry of that. If you run burst of queries all locking for updates, that could hog the connections as every other one would be on halt unless lock is released, and then to be aquired by the next query / job and the cycle continues

Comment: @danblack. the queries are created by Laravel and from what I can see, they do not use SKIP LOCKED. Sample query from "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" -:  | 4191507 | **** | 127.0.0.1:***  | **** | Execute     |    233 | Statistics                                                    | select * from `jobs` where `id` = 96515232 limit 1 for update

Comment: Edit question with Laravel implementation used. Admins seem right, a `select.. for update` implies a transaction which should be terminated once the job is complete.